# Textbox with recomendations as you type

Tags: google-app-maker

I am making a system to input some paperwork into a digital database.
In said database there are preset Clients, but there are quite a few of them (100+).

That said, when the user has to select a Client, I want to make it as swiftly as possible, and thought of having him start typing the client name, and have a sort of "dropdown" come out of the textbox with a _startsWith filter, and use directional arrows+enter to select. Similar to history on browsers?

Is there anyway to implement such a thing on a Textbox?
Right now I have am filtering a Table with the textbox, and have the user click on the tableRow to select the Client.

Any other ideas are welcome too.
Thank you for reading!

Comment: The SuggestBox widget does what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

The widget [Suggest Box](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/input-widgets#suggest-box) is exactly what you're looking for. See link for documentation.